# Select records by parents and childs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with records when some records are parents of other.

I have a column `parent` that with zero value means that is the parent. When is a child it has the `id of the parent record`.

What I need is to list the record by order, parent and childs.

My table `TOOLS`:

```
ID   | order | parent | name
100  | 1     | 0      | X
200  | 2     | 0      | Y
150  | 0     | 100    | X.1
300  | 0     | 200    | Y.1
```

I need the following result:

```
ID   | order | parent | name
100  | 1     | 0      | X
150  | 0     | 100    | X.1
200  | 2     | 0      | Y
300  | 0     | 200    | Y.1
```

How can I order this?

If I use this query

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when parent = 0 then id else parent end), order desc;
```

The result is this:

```
ID   | order | parent | name
200  | 2     | 0      | Y
300  | 0     | 200    | Y.1
100  | 1     | 0      | X
150  | 0     | 100    | X.1
```

And if I change the to `order asc` it put the records with `order = 0` at the top...

Look this [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=834a5c7d3c640ff9f251856bea80709a)

Thank you

Comment: Which database are you working on? This way we can best tailor the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

In this case, you can use `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when parent = 0 then id else parent end), order desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ff6567e07b1e64eaa9798fe9143f7f49) is a SQL Fiddle that demonstrates that this works on your original question.

Comment: please look this example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=834a5c7d3c640ff9f251856bea80709a

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a value the provides the desired order.  One way to do that is to construct a materialized path that encodes your order criteria.  Since you are using SQL Server you could use its hierarchyid data type for this, however, the real *magic* is in building the materialized path itself, of which I'll show two versions, one used with the hierarchyid (`path`) and one without (`path2`):

```
with cte as (
  -- Anchor Part
  select id, [order], parent, name, 1 level
       , cast('/'+cast(tools.id as varchar(10))+'/' as varchar(4000)) path
       , cast(cast(tools.id as binary(4)) as varbinary(4000)) path2
    from TOOLS
   where parent = 0

  union all

  -- Recursive Part
  select tools.*
       , level+1
       , cast(path+cast(tools.id as varchar(10))+'/' as varchar(4000))
       , cast(path2+cast(tools.id as binary(4)) as varbinary(4000))
    from tools
    join cte
      on tools.parent = cte.id
)
select id
     , [order]
     , parent
     , name
     , level
     , path
     , cast(path as hierarchyid) hid
     , path2
  from cte order by hid
```

In the above query, a recursive common table expression is used to walk the tree and build the two example paths. The first path, while it would work as a sort column on its own with your current IDs, would begin to fail as soon as you had IDs with a length other than three digits as the levels most significant digits would not necessarily align correctly. The cast to heirarchyid in the final query resolves that issue.  The second path can be use directly as a sort key since it casts each level of the path to a four byte binary value, as such it can handle IDs up to 4,294,967,295 and path a length (tree depth) of 1000 levels and does not need a final cast to any other data types.